# Net-standard, с помощью чего работать с пикселями вместо Bitmap?

Tags: c#, изображения, xamarin, .net-standard, imagesource

Работаю с `Xamarin`, обнаружил, что в `.net standard` отсутствует класс `Bitmap`, какие библиотеки можно использовать вместо него? 
Задача стоит в обработке изображения(работа с пикселями), например наложение фильтра

Необходимо, чтобы была возможность конвертации из `ImageSource` в этот формат

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722409/ ?

Comment: [Cannot find Bitmap Class in Class Library (.NET Standard)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46722409/2881286)